# WiFi problems with two routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a network issue. We have DSL, it runs into a WiFi router. **That** router has two ethernet cables running out.  One goes to my house where I have another WiFi router hooked up. It **was** working, and then just quit one day.

I bought a new router (long story) and hooked it up, but I have no internet connection. I have done a lot of looking to see why. I saw an answer of yours about having two routers.  The first one in the chain is Linksys3000.  Mine at home is Linksys1200. Based on what I read, I set the 3000 to Static IP and mine to DHCP. Still no success.

I then (still with same IP config) changed the IP address of the 3000 to 192.168.1.1 and mine 192.168.1.2.  Still no luck.  I really don't have a clue what I'm doing.  How can I rectify the problem?

What do I need to do?  I was going to set my router (1200) to static IP, to see if that would help. But have not yet and I'm not sure I want to. Maybe it will create more issues.

Thank you!

Comment: Generally the first router (the one connected to DSL) should be configured normally as a Router (Out of box configuration), the second router that's plugged into the first router should be put into "Bridge Mode"

Answer (score 0):

First, verify you can get one router connected to your DSL and working.

Remember, the line from the DSL box that goes to your router needs to be plugged into the WAN/Internet port of your first router.  Be sure to test your connectivity with a laptop or desktop and make sure you get internet access before you add on a second router.

Then, when you're ready to add a second router, plug a cable from any of the LAN ports on the router connected to the DSL, to the second router's WAN/Internet port.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the DHCP server on the second router - you can optionally set it to a static IP.Connect the second router to the first LAN to LAN not WAN. Both routers must have the same IP range.

Comment: I'll give it a shot this! I forgot my landlord has a router in his house as well, so...don't know of this will muddy things. I'm pretty sure his is still working fine.